# Dual boot two separate hard drives

Tags: boot, dual-boot, hard-drive

I have an Acer E5 and I have two drives, one SSD with Ubuntu 16.04 and one HDD with Windows 10. Everything works perfect but when I boot into Ubuntu apart from the main SSD, hard drive is also working. Is this normal? I don't think so. Is there a way to get only the hard drive work I use at that moment?

Comment: Yes of course that is normal. I would have put the OS files of BOTH on the SSD and use the HDD for your personal data.  "Is there a way to work only the hard drive i use at that moment? " Remove it from /etc/fstab

Comment: Hello thank you for your answer! 
If i remove it when i boot, in the grub menu if i select windows is it going to boot to windows  Or should i have it to the fstab file???

Comment: What happens at the Grub menu has nothing to do with the Ubuntu's fstab.